# Peter Pan & the Pirate: How did Peter become symbiotically linked to Neverland?

Tags: cartoon, magical-theory, peter-pan

In the **Peter Pan & the Pirates** episode *The Neverscroll,* it's established that Peter is magically linked to the fate of Neverland.

To quote Tinkerbell:

> "Peter Pan *is* Never Land...and Neverland is *he!*"

It's shown that if part of the Neverscroll, a magical piece of parchment which maps all of Neverland and can be magically used to remake the landscape, is erased, Peter suffers great pain and could even die. *Altering* it doesn't seem to have any negative effects, but removing anything completely can **physically hurt** Peter.

This is taken further, or at least supported, in the episode *Ages of Pan*, where Peter allows himself to magically grow up, but as a result "loses his belief" in Neverland. Another fairy tells the lost boys that:

> "if Peter Pan *doesn't* believe in Never Land, Never Land will *fade away!*"

Is there any canon or expanded stories that also show a version of Peter Pan being the "spiritual ruler" of Never Land, or is there any explanation for how this symbiosis was achieved in this particular series.

Answer (score 5):

This symbiosis goes back to the original novelization of the stage play, called "[Peter and Wendy](http://read.gov/books/pageturner/peter_wendy/#page/2/mode/2up)", published in 1911.

In there it explains that Neverland is basically an attempt at a map of a child's mind, and each one is different.

Page 8-9

> I don't know whether you have seen a map of a person's mind. Doctors sometimes draw maps of other parts of you, and your own map can become intensely interesting, but catch them trying to draw a map of a child's mind, which is not only confused, but keeps going round all the time. There are zigzag lines on it, just like your temperature on a card, and these are probably roads on the island, for the Neverland is always more or less an island...

Further corroborating that each one has their own island:

Page 9-10

> Of course, the Neverlands vary a good deal. John's for instance, had a lagoon with flamingoes flying over it at which John was shooting, while Michael, who was very small, had a flamingo with lagoons flying over it.

Later, they recognize their islands when flying to Neverland with Peter, which annoys him, detailed on pages 64-65. The final suggestion that without their owner, the Neverlands fade away is detailed on page 75, the beginning of the chapter titled "The Island Come True".

> Feeling that Peter was on his way back, the Neverland had again woke into life. We ought to use the pluperfect and say wakened, but woke is better and was always used by Peter.
>
> In his absence, things are usually quiet on the island. The fairies take an hour longer in the morning, the beasts attend to their young, the redskinds feed heavily for six days and nights, and when pirates and lost boys meet they merely bite their thumbs at each other. But with the coming of Peter, who hates lethargy, they are all under way again: if you put your ear to the ground now, you would hear the whole island seething with life.

While this doesn't explicitly say that Neverland dies without Peter Pan, there is a clear progression of each individual island being the creation of a small child, and that without the child, the island goes dormant or disappears (For children that grow up and forget about Neverland). It also shows that Peter is the driving force for his Neverland.

Comment: "the driving force", huh? Well, considering the liberties that this version of Peter Pan took in expanding the Neverland lore, it's as good an explanation as any. I suppose it wouldn't exactly apply to other versions [**Hook** for instance, where Peter **totally forgot** about the place, but it still thrived without him, or **pan** where it existed before him] but if this comes from J.M.'s own imagination, it would be hard to argue some form of visceral or magical connection isn't strongly implied.

Comment: @RussRainford - Not sure what you mean by "this version". This is the novelization of the stage play, both written by JM Barrie. Everything that came after would either be continuation or departure.

Comment: by "this version" I meant the show itself. It changed a lot from the source material to be more palatable to a daily viewing TV show; Peter's clothes were brown as opposed to green, Wendy had black hair, Tinkerbell could actually _talk_ to others and was pretty powerful magically, Hook was **massively different,** bearing a more hulking, erudite and actively violent threat, and the other pirates were given deeper backstories and personalities. A lot of liberties were taken, which is why I thought Peter's symbiosis with the land could have just been another new added story element.

Comment: @RussRainford - Ah, I see what you are getting at. Makes sense. Not really added, but definitely embellished.

Comment: @RussRainford I'd say some of those liberties are actually closer to the original source; Peter's clothes should be brown, as they are made from dead leaves, for example. ("clad in skeleton leaves and the juices that ooze out of trees").

Comment: @Showsni you make a good point, but again, this was early 90s kids TV; this show was notable for its depth and incredible detail, and its adding to the overall magical aesthetic of J.M.'s novel. The Girl who lives in the Moon, for instance... having grown up predominantly on the _disney_ version of Peter Pan, I had no idea if she was a canon character from a story within a story,  or a new creation entirely. The Native tribe was _definbitely_ treated with a _bit_ more respect than the Disney "red skins", which to me showed the more modern influences.